# echo in shell script replaces variable with following characters

Tags: http, shell, curl, awk

When using `curl` and `awk` to get the content-length for an HTTP request, the resulting variable gets "erased" when used in an `echo` statement with following characters.

Why?

```
#!/bin/sh
CONF_CORE_URL="http://www.google.com/"
CMD_SIZE_TARGET=$(curl -sS -I $CONF_CORE_URL | awk '/Content-Length/ {print $2}')
echo "${CMD_SIZE_TARGET}"
echo "${CMD_SIZE_TARGET} test"
exit 0
```

Expected output:

```
222
222 test
```

Actual output:

```
222
 test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$CMD_SIZE_TARGET` has a `\r` at the end that you will need to strip first.

Comment: Spot on. Thank you Ignacio. I'll accept your answer once SO lets me (in 10 mins).